# PHP when entering text in a form, when submitted I need it to pull an image file from the path inputed

Tags: php, html

```
<td><b>Image File Name</b></td><td><input type='text' name='imgfn' id='imgfn'     value='$imgfn'>

<?PHP
        if(isset($_POST['imgfn']))
        {
            echo "
                <img src='img/$imgfn' alt='$imgfn' style='width:200px;height:200px;'> 
            ";
        }
    ?>
```

so if my image is dog.jpg, in my form I would enter dog.jpg in the text box and when submitted it will pop up the dog image

Comment: variable `$imgfn` is not set, it's null. You haven't defined it anywhere, only checked if it is posted

Comment: well wouldn't $imgfn = what ever is entered in the form?

Comment: If you're going to post a question consisting entirely of a piece of code, please at least make the code readable.

Answer (score 0):

I do wonder if there are many things to discuss here, but let me start with this being a more sane method of producing what it is you're asking for.  There is no sense in offering a buffet if you only serve cold chicken.

Just show them the list they can pick from.  Or tell them there is no food.

```
<?php
  $dir = '/img/';
  $imgs = glob($dir.'*.*');
  if (empty($imgs)) :
    die('this server has no images...this form will do nothing. ending output now.');
  else :
    ?>
    <td><b>Image File Name</b></td>
    <td>
      <select name="imgfn">
        <?php
          foreach ($imgs as &$img) :
            ?>
              <option value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '\"', basename($img)); ?>"><?php echo basename($img); ?></option>
            <?php
          endforeach;
        ?>
      </select>
      <?PHP
        if (!empty($_POST['imgfn']) && in_array($dir.$_POST['imgfn'], $imgs)) {
          echo "<img src='img/$imgfn' alt='$imgfn' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>";
        }
      ?>
    </td>
    <?php
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: btw, i'm pretty sure putting @ on the variable passed to empty() will raise a concern in the logs; definitely remove that.

Comment: my directory is C:\xampp\htdocs\csc423_source\public_html\img so img is a folder in the root dir. I have a lot of photos in img how come it says server has no images?

Comment: <?php
  $imgs = glob('img/*.*');
  die('<pre>'.print_r($imgs, 1));
?>
shows no images?  (note i removed the slash that made it absolute to your DOCUMENT_ROOT, wondering if that would help...is your file in public_html?)